# What are the archiving policies of arXiv?

Tags: arxiv, backup-archiving

In this [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/47414/929) it is suggested that arXiv, as its name would suggest, is archival. One of Beall's criteria is that a publisher is potentially predatory if it

> Has no policies or practices for digital preservation, meaning that if the 
>   journal ceases  operations,  all  of  the  content  disappears  from  the 
>   internet.

The only thing I can find about digital preservation on the [arXiv website](http://arxiv.org/help/primer) is

> arXiv submissions are meant to be available in perpetuity. Thus, arXiv has high technical standards for the files that are submitted.

While it is good that the articles are in a format which will allow access in perpetuity, the primer says nothing about what happens if arXiv ceases operations. What is the arXiv policy in regards to digital preservation?

Comment: I would presume that the arXiv is simply too big to fail.

Comment: @Arno I would presume that perpetuity is a long time for things to "just work".

Comment: The arXiv also benefits from not having a single point of failure. By design it has [some geographical redundancy](http://arxiv.org/help/mirrors).

Comment: I don't really understand the relevance of Beall's criteria to arXiv. As far as I understand, arXiv does not have an editorial board that operates in a similar manner to a journal's editorial board, nor does it conduct peer review, for example... Is this meant to suggest that arXiv is a predatory publisher?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I used Beall's criteria because it nicely described what I was looking for, not because I think of arXiv as predatory.

Comment: StackExchange is the same way. If StackExchange were to implode tomorrow, well, our questions are gone. But you should also weigh the likelihood of that versus the severity of that.

Comment: @Compass but I have never seen Stack Exchange claim to be archival and it is not in their name.

Comment: @StrongBad It's not in our name, but Stack Exchange, at least Stack Overflow, encourages information to be brought into the fold as opposed to linked as the guarantee of the question being useful and non-volatile depends on its content being hosted on the server. The service is useless if it isn't archived, even if it doesn't call itself an archive, it is still an archive <_<

Comment: Also, monthly, the entire text-based content is, in fact, uploaded to archive.org.

Comment: BioRxiv is [backed up by CLOCKSS](https://twitter.com/biorxivpreprint/status/426444678368878592). It would be great if this were true of arXiv as well.

Comment: @Compass : That's simply false. StackExchange publishes Creative Commons licensed dumps at regular intervals. If StackExchange would implode someone else would publish one of the dumps.

Comment: @Christian I was referring the conceptual point of Stack being designed as a primary service of being a Q&A site as opposed to the secondary service of being an archival site.

Comment: @Compass : Part of StackExchange design are data-dumps and an open license. That's to make sure that the data can continue to be used long after a question got answered. If StackExchange would implode the data wouldn't be gone.

Comment: @Christian just because data is made available does not mean someone is actively archiving it. If that was the case, the answer to this question would be that arXiv makes the data available.

Comment: @StrongBad : There doesn't have to be someone who actively tries to "archive" the data. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-stack-exchange-content-copiers-here/173542#173542 gives you a list of various parties that do try to host mirrors. There are various machine learning projects that have use for the dataset as training data. But even if you look at people who archive more formally the Internet Archive is currently the main host for the StackExchange dumps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [their FAQ](http://arxiv.org/help/support/faq#7D):

> **What are CUL's preservation strategies?**
>
> Digital preservation refers to a range of managed activities to
>   support the long-term maintenance of bitstreams. These activities
>   ensure that digital objects are usable (intact and readable),
>   retaining all quantities of authenticity, accuracy, and functionality
>   deemed to be essential when articles (and other associated materials)
>   were ingested. Formats accepted by arXiv have been selected based on
>   their archival value (TeX/LaTeX, PDF, HTML) and the ability to process
>   all source files is actively monitored. The underlying bits are
>   protected by standard backup procedures at the Cornell campus.
>   Off-site backup facilities in New York City provide geographic
>   redundancy. The complete content is replicated at arXiv's mirror sites
>   around the world, and additional managed tape backups are taken at Los
>   Alamos National Laboratory. CUL has an archival repository to support
>   preservation of critical content from institutional resources,
>   including arXiv. We anticipate storing all arXiv documents, both in
>   source and processed form, in this repository. There will be ongoing
>   incremental ingest of new material. We expect that CUL will bear the
>   preservation costs for arXiv, leveraging the archival infrastructure
>   developed for the library system.

It looks like they're relying on a) multiple offsite mirrors; b) periodic stored backups at LANL; and c) deposit in the institutional repository at Cornell.

It's a little unclear if that deposit is actually happening yet or is still part of a long-term plan, but it's worth noting that the arXiv program director is also the librarian responsible for Cornell's digital preservation work, so it's unlikely to have been forgotten about!

Comment: The link is now dead, and I couldn't find up-to-date information. Does someone know if there is info available somewhere about their current archival policies?

Answer (score 12):

This is answered in the FAQ for the [arXiv Membership Program](http://arxiv.org/help/support/faq#7D):

> CUL [Cornell University Library] has an archival repository to support preservation of critical content from institutional resources, including arXiv. We anticipate storing all arXiv documents, both in source and processed form, in this repository. There will be ongoing incremental ingest of new material. We expect that CUL will bear the preservation costs for arXiv, leveraging the archival infrastructure developed for the library system.

The same FAQ also tells you about the current funding model (up until some years ago arXiv was entirely funded and ran by the Cornell University Library; now funding comes from also the Simons Foundation as well as other participating university libraries).

In terms of Cornell's digital preservation policies, I cannot find a full description online (probably just due to my weak google-fu today); but [this would be person to contact and ask](https://www.library.cornell.edu/about/inside/departments/dsps).

Comment: The link is now dead, and I couldn't find up-to-date information. Does someone know if there is info available somewhere about their current archival policies?

Comment: I would suggesting emailing the arXiv staff. There is a contact link in the help page on arXiv.

Answer (score 6):

I asked arXiv on October 4, 2023:

> I am involved in an overlay journal whose articles are published on arXiv, and we are asked by the Free Journal Network about our long-term archival policies.
>
> For this reason I would like to know if there is a long-term archival policy for arXiv articles: are there backups or continuity plans in place to ensure that the articles are preserved if arXiv is unable to continue operation?
>
> Also, is there publicly available information about this? I could not find anything in the FAQ or in the help about long-term preservation.

I got the following reply one day later:

> Thank you for reaching out. We are committed to permanently archiving the content that is submitted to and hosted by arXiv and operate under policies designed to ensure long-term access to the scholarly record. However, at this time, arXiv is not engaged in formal preservation activities. We hope to implement a preservation strategy in the future.

So the answer seems to be that **arXiv does not currently have any long-term preservation strategy**.

That said, in practice, in addition to the current bulk data access options, it looks like there is a downloadable copy of the data here https://archive.org/details/arxiv-bulk (though it was apparently last updated in 2020).

Comment: This is really an important answer. Thanks.