# What is the backup strategy of online-only journals/repositories on the very long term?

Tags: journals, publishers, online-publication, digital-libraries

Disseminating printed documents in many places on the planet is a very robust "backup" strategy for scientific literature. Printed documents (and other forms of ink-on-paper documents), or fragments of them, are known to last for millennia and with a high redundancy (many copies spread in many geographic locations), the chances of being able to reconstruct the original content is high.

All current electronic data storage require continuous catering (electrical power and servers maintenance) or frequent re-copying (i.e. of laser discs, magnetic hard drives, etc.) to last more than a few decades.

**How do online-only journals and articles repositories intend to ensure very long-term archival of their content?**

Comment: For interest see also: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28505/computer-that-lasts-for-centuries (Speculative)

Comment: @Oxinabox looks interesting, to clarify I'm interested in the actual policy that journals have nowadays. I understand that "They have none" is a possible answer.

Comment: I asked specifically about the arXiv policy here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47416/what-are-the-archiving-policies-of-arxiv

Comment: I'm seriously tempted to ask the symmetric question: "Disseminating online documents in many places on the planet is a very robust strategy for scientific literature... **How do paper-only journals intend to ensure very long-term archival of their content?**"

Comment: @JeffE wouldn't the answer to that be the same way they have been for decades?

Comment: @JeffE ... For paper archives: One change has been to used acid-free paper, so that it takes much longer to become brittle and disintegrate.

Comment: @JeffE the answer to that question is stated in my post.

Comment: Many modern libraries have developed a habit of discarding paper versions of documents because they have electronic versions that take much less storage space. Books go out of print and are damaged, destroyed, lost, or discarded, and publishers go out of business, sometimes before their content can be digitally preserved. My question stands.

Comment: @GEdgar: acid free paper is good, but what do we know about long-term preservation of laser printing? Most Springer or Elsevier journals are now printed with on-demand laser printing, and given their look (at least in math) I would bet it's not the top quality in that technology.

Comment: @JeffE it's true that if libraries start to burn their books, that will weaken the strategy. Although I'm sure not everyone everywhere is actively destroying printed content. But so the assumption is that there will be infinite monetary support to maintain the online repositories?

Comment: No, of course not. But neither do I assume that there will be infinite monetary support to maintain repositories containing megatons of cellulose.

Comment: @CapeCode: I haven't heard of any libraries burning their books, but many of them sell books that haven't been checked out for a certain number of years.  Of course in that case the books still exist, somewhere, but the content is less effectively preserved for posterity if it's scattered all over the world.

Comment: @CapeCode Hosting physical books costs money https://leverpress.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/CourantandNielsen.pdf suggests 0.86$ per year for the cheapest way to store books and 4.26$ for storage at a place where it's easily accessible by library users. The amount of money you need to maintain online repositories is orders of magnitude less.

Answer (score 3):

Most publishers use a preservation network such as [Portico](http://www.portico.org/digital-preservation/services/e-journal-preservation-service) or [LOCKSS](http://www.lockss.org/). The principle is that numerous electronic copies are saved, and released in case of certain events (e.g. the publisher stops permanently giving access to the works).

Answer (score 2):

Open access journals and article repositories have a good option of ensuring very-long term access that is similar to how printed documents were handled in the past: **Wide dissemination over several repositories**.

In the life sciences, open access articles are often deposited in additional repositories by publishers themselves, for example at [Pubmed Central](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/) or it's European equivalent [Europe PMC](https://europepmc.org). I think also additional repositories actively mirror some open access journals - at least I frequently seem to get results of such additional repositories through internet searches. That means even if the publisher goes bankrupt and shuts down its servers, the papers should still be easily accessible through these mirror repositories. See for example [Biomed Central's statement on permanency of articles.](http://www.biomedcentral.com/about/policies/permanency-of-articles)

This strategy is only possible for open access journals, since only those typically allow redistribution of their articles and thus permit the mirror repositories to act as they do. I have no idea how commercial, non-open access publishers handle this problem.

Comment: *This strategy is only possible for open access journals* not really, subscription journals also post pre- or postprints on external repositories.

Comment: @CapeCode The key word in your sentence is _allow_.  If they wanted to ensure long-term availability, journals would *require* wide dissemination over several repositories.

Comment: Besides, how is dissemination over several repositories better than having multiple replicates of a database on several commercial servers?

Comment: @CapeCode Because it's several institutions as well. If a publisher goes bankrupt, I'd expect all replicates to become inaccessible simultaneously, if no specific counter-measures are in place.

Answer (score -1):

Currently lib.gen/sci-hub build an archive of all papers and textbooks. Publishers fight the legal battle to stop the project but it's highly unlikely that they will stop lib.gen/sci-hub and it's various mirrors in every country of the world. Elsevier might win the suit in the US but they probably know why they don't pick the fight in Russia where the lib.gen/sci-hub servers reside.

There are applications like IBM's Watson that work better if they have access to more data. That means that companies like IBM, Google, Baidu and Facebook have an interest to have all the data of all scientific papers.

Isn't it expensive to store all that data? No, it isn't. In 2014 Facebook added [4 petabyte](https://research.facebook.com/blog/facebook-s-top-open-data-problems/) of data per day to it's database. That's likely more data than all scientific papers together. All the arxiv PDF's together are [270 GB](https://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data_s3).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, either at a literal level (sci-hub is certainly not how most journals intend to do long-term archiving) or in spirit (sci-hub faces exactly the same long-term archiving challenges as publishers do, plus the added difficulty of not having all the content in the first place).

Comment: Note that the 270 GB figure is apparently as of February 2012, and likely is quite a bit larger by now.